# how to use variable in sed '3d' ../log/file2.txt > ../log/file8.txt

Tags: shell, sed

I want to delete third line of file named file2. Its running successfully.No Issues with it.

```
sed '3d' ../log/file2.txt > ../log/file8.txt
```

Now i want to use variable `VAR1` (where `VAR1=2`).

I wrote the following command

```
sed "${VAR1+1}d" ../log/file2.txt > ../log/file8.txt
```

but this command deleting the 2nd line. No error while executing the command.But I am not getting expected output

Please help me
How to use sed in this command to get the correct line to be deleted

Comment: You have been posting pieces of the same question during last hours. What about doing some research and then asking rather than asking on each new step you want to go ahead?

Comment: please this is the last 1.I did the R & D..but still dint find d ans..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sed "$((VAR1+1))d" ../log/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a line using variable and `awk`

```
var1=4
awk NR!=v v=$var1 ../log/file2.txt > ../log/file8.txt
```

This removes the `4th` line in `file2`

To make it more robust, use qutes

```
awk 'NR!=v' v="$var1" file
```